# Function tab-completion not matching that of wrapped command

Tags: autocomplete, function, fish

I've got a function defined in my fish shell:

```bsh
function cl --wraps=cd
    cd $argv && ls -l --color=auto
end
```

According to `man function`, the `--wraps` option "causes the function to inherit completions from the given wrapped command."

However, when I type `cl`  and start to tab-complete, I'm shown options which include non-directories (like .c files).  However, when I type `cd`  and then tab-complete, I'm only shown directories.

Did I define my function incorrectly?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. If you run `functions cl` does it show the `wraps` argument? What does `fish --version` show?

Comment: Yeah, it shows the `--wraps=cd`.  The version of fish is 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/4693) which was fixed in fish shell version 3.3.0. Upgrade to a newer fish and it should fixed.